# Image of the trace operator on W^{1,1}

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Let $\Omega \subset R^n$ be a bounded region with Lipschitz boundary. Is the trace operator $T: W^{1,1}(\Omega)\rightarrow L^1(\partial \Omega)$ surjective? If not, what is the image?

Answer (score 4):

> The trace operator $T:W^{1,1}(\Omega)\to L^1(\partial\Omega)$ is
>   surjective.

This is a classical result of Gagliardo [1], see Theorem 18.13 in [2].

In other words for every function $g\in L^1(\partial\Omega)$ there is a function $Eg\in W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ such that $T(Eg)=g$. However, as was proved by Peetre [3], there is **no bounded linear extension operator** $E:L^1(\partial\Omega)\to W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. That is the extension operator $E$ is non-linear.

The original proof of Peetre is difficult to understand, but there are more direct (still difficult) proofs, see e.g. [4].

[1] **E. Gagliardo**, Caratterizzazioni delle tracce sulla frontiera relative ad alcune classi di funzioni in n variabili.  *Rend. Sem. Mat. Univ. Padova* 27 1957 284–305.

[2] **G. Leoni**, *A first course in Sobolev spaces.* Second edition. Graduate Studies in Mathematics, 181. American Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2017.

[3] **J. Peetre**, A counterexample connected with Gagliardo's trace theorem. Special issue dedicated to Władysław Orlicz on the occasion of his seventy-fifth birthday. *Comment. Math.* Special Issue 2 (1979), 277–282.

[4] **A. Pełczyński, M. Wojciechowski**, Sobolev spaces in several variables in $L^1$-type norms are not isomorphic to Banach lattices. *Ark. Mat.* 40 (2002), 363–382.

Answer (score 1):

It is surjective for a $C^1$ boundary, see [Demengel & Demengel](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/bfm%3A978-1-4471-2807-6%2F1.pdf), section 3.3. Following the proof will probably answer your question.

Comment: You could correct the link to the book by Demengel & Demengel, because it does not work.

Comment: @PiotrHajlasz now updated